# Setup CircleCI for ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, .net, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm setting CI/CD Pipeline for my ASP.NET project using CircleCI.

CircleCI already supported Window Machine. So I think it's possible to use CircleCI for ASP.NET proejct. 
By following the [documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/hello-world-windows/) of CircleCI, I can config for `.NET Core` project (because I can use command line to build and run `exe` file of .NET Core project)

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  win: circleci/windows@1.0.0

jobs:
  build:
    executor:
      name: win/vs2019
      shell: powershell.exe
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - dotnet-packages-v1-{{ checksum "circleci-demo-windows.csproj" }}
      - run:
          name: "Install project dependencies"
          command: dotnet.exe restore
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - C:\Users\circleci\.nuget\packages
          key: dotnet-packages-v1-{{ checksum "circleci-demo-windows.csproj" }}

      - run:
          name: "Run Build step"
          command: dotnet.exe publish -c Release -r win10-x64
      - run:
          name: "Test the executable"
          command: .\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\win10-x64\publish\circleci-demo-windows.exe
      - store_artifacts:
          path: .\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\win10-x64\publish\circleci-demo-windows.exe
```

But It seems like I can't use commands such as `dotnet.exe publish...` for .NET framework. So how I can setup CircleCi for ASP.NET ?

Sorry for my naive question, I have searched around but couldn't find any tutorials about CircleCI and .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

The `dotnet.exe` (or can be simply called `dotnet`) command is valid for .NET Core related projects. It cannot be used for .NET Framework projects at all.

If you want to publish .NET Framework projects, you should use or run MSBUILD instead of run `dotnet`. The CircleCI documentation is somehow not complete, because it gives you impression that you can use `dotnet` to publish .NET Framework projects, but it actually can't.

Comment: So where is MSBUILD on CircleCI machine ?